# Firefox showing an odd string of characters in the location bar

Tags: macos, .htaccess, firefox

I've seen this a few times recently, but never paid attention to it.  Now that it's causing problems, though I need to figure it out.

Sometimes when I visit a site in Firefox 13 on the Mac I get this strange string attached to the end of the URL in the location bar.

It always starts with "#.T_" and is usually something like "#.T_3HiHDevA8".

For the life of me I can't figure out what's causing it.  It only comes up on the first load

I do have a bit of rewriting going on, but I don't understand how that could be adding things to the location bar.  Here's my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]+)/?$ / [QSA]
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 'qsappend|QSA' (query string append)
>
> This flag forces the rewrite
>   engine to append a query string part of the substitution string to the
>   existing string, instead of replacing it. Use this when you want to
>   add more data to the query string via a rewrite rule.

The [QSA flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) indicates to append the query string of the subsitution string.

Taking a futher look:

```
^([a-zA-Z_]+)/?$
```

1. ^ = Beginning of URL
2. ( ) = Groups a series of pattern elements
3. [ ] = Denotes a set of possible matches
4. a-zA-Z_ = Alpha-numerical characters and underscore '_' only
5. + = indicates there is one or more of the preceding element
6. / = Forward slash in URL
7. ? = Match preceeding 0 or 1 times
8. $ = End of URL

Apply the above logic to your rule: `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]+)/?$ / [QSA]` will redirect the matches per the breakdown above to '/' and append the query string, assuming the URL does not eqaul to '/'.